# Plot with MATLAB

Tags: matlab

everybody,

I have a new problem with matlab, I want to generate a graph using Plot !

I wrote that:

```
X=[0, 2.5];
P = 0.1 * ones(N,11);
N=length(X);
for n=1:N
    for t=1:10
    P(n,t+1)=X(n)*P(n,t)*[1-P(n,t)];
    end
end
plot(t,P)
```

But again the computer answer me that :

```
??? Error using ==> plot
Vectors must be the same lengths.

Error in ==> test at 10
plot(t,P)
```

I do not have any idea of why ?

Comment: Please format your question correctly; you can sort out the code by selecting it and clicking the button marked **{}** in the editor.

Comment: I will, sorry to disturb you by the way...

Answer (score 2):

The variable t in your plot command is no a vector but just the scalar 10. You have to call the plot command instead with

```
plot(1:11,P);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! 
Do you know How can I do something like thaht : http://hpics.li/57b346a if I substitute X by Psi, because Now All my graphs are together...

Comment: You have to use the `subplot` command for this type of plots. Take a look at the Matlab help with `doc subplot` for more details.

Comment: I think you want `plot(0:10, P)`, but I can't be sure.